# What does it mean for an operation to be a fundamental operation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I read the following in a book - "Re-indexing in pandas is a process that makes the data in a Series conform to a set of labels. It is used by pandas to perform much of the alignment process and is hence a **fundamental** operation." I'd like to know what makes this operation fundamental within the pandas library.

Comment: Well, as the book says, it is fundamental because "It is used by pandas to perform much of the alignment process".

Comment: Some other operations within the book are categorised to be fundamental, and they don't necessarily perform any alignment. I'm looking to find the definition of 'fundamental' within the context of the Pandas framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a technical definition of "fundamental" for Pandas. It sounds like the author is pointing out that maintaining the correct connection between indices (both the axis 0 index called "index" and the axis 1 index called "columns") is what makes Pandas Pandas. And the almost magical way that complex reindexing "just works" is why Pandas remains king. So yeah, fundamental.

I would recommend James Powell's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oazUQPrs8nw), especially around minute 18 where he discusses "Why do we even use Pandas?". TLDR If you are not making use of the indices, you may be using the wrong library.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) you can see how useful reindexing is. It happens behind the scenes when  Dataframes/Series are being combined. The behavior of pandas is defined in such a way so that implicit reindexing is used a lot.

“Fundamental” means:

> being the most basic or most important thing on which other things depend

- [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fundamental).

There *can* be several fundamental things.

And their definition is not mathematically strict - the authors have called some features “fundamental” because of the **feeling** that a significant part of other functionality depends on these features.